# how to manage custom data table in Umbraco back office?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

Is there an out of box way to manage data of custom tables in Umbraco back office ?

I will need to access data in MVC site pages. Want to use Umbraco back office for this and give a html table / gird like interface with data where user can do CRUD operations on data records.

how it can be done ? Is there a feature or datatype to support this ?

Please guide and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at uSiteBuilder for Umbraco:
http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/tutorials?id=22389

Also:
Document Type: a List View Type

Some info:
http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/a-first-look-at-umbraco-container-content-types#.VKqX9WSsWGg